# Subspaces of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that if $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of vector space $V$ such that $V=U\cup W$ then either $V=U$ or $V=W$.
I am thinking one should use bases for $U$ and for $W$ somehow to show that bases for $V$ are equal to either bases for $W$ or for $U$.

Any suggestions where to start welcome.

Comment: Try with $\mathbb{R}^2$, first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $V = U \cup W$. If $U \subseteq W$, then $W = U \cup W = V$. Similarly for $W \subseteq U$, we get $U = V$.

So, let $U,W \subsetneq V$. Then, as we have seen, $U \not\subseteq W$ and $W \not\subseteq U$, and there are vectors $u \in U \setminus W$ and $w \in W \setminus U$.

Let $v = u + w \in V$. What can we say about it?

- If $v \in U$, then $w = v - u \in U$, which is a contradiction.
- If $v \in W$, then $u = v - w \in W$, which is a contradiction.

We conclude that $v \not\in U \cup W = V$, which is a contradiction. Hence, we cannot have $U,W \subsetneq V$.